# How do I programmatically open energy saving settings in oppo device?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I am trying to open energy savings settings of device oppo-CPH1609 for a specific application which looks like this.
[Screenshot of settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQniR.png).

I have tried following methods for doing it

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I have also tried to change action as

```
Settings.EXTRA_BATTERY_SAVER_MODE_ENABLED
```

Any Help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS),0);
  //0 is request code
```

And in `onActivityResult` method, you could handle returned result.

Comment: Not the result i wanted. Its opening power saving mode of battery.